# if else inside for loop consulting multiple dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am having issues with the following code because i'm checking multiple dictionaries for a value.

When this value is not found i am getting multiple prints of 'not found'. The else statement should check for all dictionaries and print 'not found' after checking all dictionaries not for each.

```
class Catalog:

    def __init__(self):
        self.movies_list = [
            {'Titulo:': 'The Ring', 'Autor:': 'random_guy', 'Genero:': 'Horror', 'Duracion:': '115 Minutos',
             'Anio:': '2002',
             'Rating:': '7.1/10'},
            {'Titulo:': 'Locos por la progra', 'Autor:': 'other_guy', 'Genero:': 'Comedy', 'Duracion:': '90 Minutos',
             'Anio:': '2000', 'Rating:': '10/10'}]

        #self.user_input
        self.x = 'The Ring'

    def search(self):
        for dict in self.movies_list:
              for i in dict.items():
                    #self.user_input
                     if self.x in i:
                            print(dict['Titulo:'])
                     else:
                            print('not found')
              break

catalog = Catalog()
catalog.search()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to return from the method if you key matched input. If nothing found then print 'not found' at the end

```
def search(self):
        for dict in self.movies_list:
              for i in dict.items():
                    #self.user_input
                     if self.x in i:
                            print(dict['Titulo:'])
                            return;

        print('not found')
```

Comment: Thanks this also clarifies the use of return as well and makes the code cleaner for me. If i am not wrong this would return to the previous iteration. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean value `found`, if you find the key make the value True. After the for loops check whether the variable is True. If it is false, dont do anything, otherwise, print not found.

I'm not sure of the syntax but it should be something like this:

```
def search(self):
    boolean found = False
    for dict in self.movies_list:
          for i in dict.items():
                #self.user_input
                 if self.x in i:
                        print(dict['Titulo:'])
                        found = True
    if not found:
         print('not found')
```

If you want to break after the first match, you can add two breaks, one of them after `found = True`, the other one is after the `outer for loop` as `if found: break`